# Xuggle or ffmpeg (newbie)

Tags: java, ffmpeg, xuggle

I am pretty new to image capturing using java.
Which is better and easy to implement Xuggle or ffmpeg for frames capturing and making a video having both audio and video. I have looked on xuggle and ffmpeg, but am unable to get a decent tutorial out of both. Any hint or tutorial will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of your question isn't entirely correct. Xuggle is a framework built around Ffmpeg to make using Ffmpeg in Java easier. Ffmpeg is what captures the video, and Xuggle is basically just a way to tell Ffmpeg what to do. If you use Xuggle, you will* be using Ffmpeg.

*You can configure it to use other codecs, but it's not too easy and rather pointless.